# How to redirect drop down menu when option is selected?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to jump to the web page when the option is selected from the third drop down menu.

Javascript:

```
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
        "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/bond1126/xvw57tn8/)

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Your questions not clear, is it the dropdown menu you want help with or opening the webpage?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean and provide some sample code or and example?

Comment: I need to add the redirect function so when you select the city it gets redirected to the web page.

Comment: `{uri:'http://msn.com', text: ['someText']}` better yet `TextLink(link, text){ this.link = link || ''; this.text = text || []; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
citySel.onchange = function(){
        window.location.href = "http://google.it";
}
```

At the bottom of `window.onload = function () {` should do the job.

You probabily want to do something like:

```
citySel.onchange = function(){
switch(citySel.value){
case "Salinas":
        window.location.href = "http://salinas.com";
break;
case "Gonzales":
    if(stateSel.value == "Something"){
        window.location.href = "http://gonzales.com";
    }else if(stateSel.value == "Else"){
        window.location.href = "http://gonzales.com";
    }
break;
}
```

Comment: but what about the value? like  switch(this.value)

Comment: @TomC. I'm not sure about what are you refering to. If you need a redirect  that will do the job! Why would you like to add a switch on the value?

Comment: @TomC. You can get the value of citySel using citySel.value

Comment: When I select "Salinas" it takes me to the particular page.

Comment: But when i select "Gonzales" it should be a different page.

Comment: You havent mentioned it in your question! In that case a switch on citySel.value should be fine!

Comment: citySel.onchange = function(){
switch(citySel.value){
case "Salinas":
        window.location.href = "http://salinas.com"
case "Gonzales":
    window.location.href = "http://gonzales.com";
}

Comment: Oops... Problem solved! It is working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Another question. What if the states have similar cities?

Comment: @TomC. Please add furher question in the initial question or on a new one, as this conversation will be likely be moved in chat. I've updated my answer, but please update your question too.

Comment: `var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Salinas", "Winston"],
        "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
    }
`'

Comment: But "Salinas" cities have different websites.

Comment: Thank you so much. Nice.

Comment: @TomC. Please accept my answer if it answers your question

Comment: You can click the tick on the left of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `onchange` handler to your city select.

```js
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
        "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
    }
    
    citySel.onchange = function () {
        if(stateSel.options.length > 0 && countySel.options.length) {
         alert('County: '+countySel.value + ' - State: ' +stateSel.value + ' - City: ' +citySel.value);
          location.href = '/'; // your link
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line can be used in an `onChange` event for the select box:

```
window.location.replace("http://YOUR-URL-HERE.com");
```

```js
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
        "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; // done   
        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
        
        
    }
    citySel.onchange = function () {
    //redirect page
     window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
</form>
```